# How can I find the bottom-right-most cell in a table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select the right-most, bottom-most cell in a `<table>` using jQuery.

It's not as easy as `$('#tableId td').last()`, because a cell may span several rows.

It should also handle `<th>` cells.

Here's my attempt so far:

```js
function fixLastCell($table){        
    var $lastCell = $table.find('td,th').last();        
    $lastCell.css('background-color', 'red');
}

fixLastCell($('#t0'));
fixLastCell($('#t1'));
fixLastCell($('#t2'));
fixLastCell($('#t3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="t0" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4 - ok</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t1" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><td>1</td><td rowspan="2">2<br> this one is</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3 <br/>this isn't the cell you're looking for</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t2" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th>TH2 - ok</th></tr>
</table>
<p>
    <table id="t3" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th rowspan="2">TH2</th></tr>
    <tr><td>3 <br/>still wrong</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's less complicated to check for the [attribute "rowspan"](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/). Depending of the success to find such, you change the value of "$lastcell".

https://jsfiddle.net/8j9jybm8/2/

```js
function fixLastCell($table){
    
 var $lastCell = $table.find('td[rowspan],th[rowspan]').last();
 var $lastCell2 = $table.find('td,th').last();
    
  if($lastCell.index() <= $lastCell2.index()){
    $lastCell = $lastCell2;
  }
    
   $lastCell.css('background-color', 'red');
}

fixLastCell($('#t0'));

fixLastCell($('#t1'));

fixLastCell($('#t2'));

fixLastCell($('#t3'));

fixLastCell($('#t4'));

fixLastCell($('#t5'));

fixLastCell($('#t6'));

fixLastCell($('#t7'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t0" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4 - ok</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t1" border="1" width="100">
    <tr><td>1</td><td rowspan="2">2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t2" border="1" width="100">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th>TH2</th></tr>
</table>
<p>
 <table id="t3" border="1" width="100">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th rowspan="2">TH2</th></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t4" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4 - ok</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t5" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><td>1</td><td rowspan="2">2<br> this one is</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3 <br/>this isn't the cell you're looking for</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t6" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th>TH2 - ok</th></tr>
</table>
<p>
    <table id="t7" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th rowspan="2">TH2</th></tr>
    <tr><td>3 <br/>still wrong</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here's my initial snippet:

```js
function fixLastCell($table){
  var $lastCell = $table.find('td[rowspan],th[rowspan]').last();
  
  if($lastCell.length === 0){
    $lastCell = $table.find('td,th').last();
  }
 
  $lastCell.css('background-color', 'red');
    
    
}

fixLastCell($('#t0'));

fixLastCell($('#t1'));

fixLastCell($('#t2'));

fixLastCell($('#t3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="t0" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4 - ok</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t1" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><td>1</td><td rowspan="2">2<br> this one is</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3 <br/>this isn't the cell you're looking for</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t2" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th>TH2 - ok</th></tr>
</table>
<p>
    <table id="t3" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th rowspan="2">TH2</th></tr>
    <tr><td>3 <br/>still wrong</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it won't work - if there is ANY cell with a rowspan in the table, that will be picked - even if it's not in the bottom-right corner. See https://jsfiddle.net/5Loye84s/2/ - check the first table

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu Oh c'mon... A little bit more effort to get your hands dirty pls ... Adapted your fiddle (with a possible example) https://jsfiddle.net/8j9jybm8/1/

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu Glad to hear that :) How about ticking my answer as correct then? ;)

Comment: OK :) Can't find a way to break it, and it's more concise than the other answers. One more nitpick: inside the `if` you could just do `$lastCell = $lastCell2` and avoid running that selector twice.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea, get the position of the table, add the width and height to get the lower most right corner of the table.

Then subtract borders and padding, and use `elementFromPoint` to get the cell at that position, which would be the lower right most cell, always, regardless of the order of the cells etc.

Something like this

```
function fixLastCell($table){
    var offset = $table.offset();

    offset.left += ($table.width() - 
                    $table.css('border-right-width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') - 
                    $table.css('padding-right').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '')) - 1;

    offset.top  += ($table.height() - 
                    $table.css('border-bottom-width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') - 
                    $table.css('padding-bottom').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '')) -1;

    var $last = $(document.elementFromPoint(offset.left, offset.top));

    return $last.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2bwn1nun/1/)

Another option would be to check if the previous cell has a rowspan of `1` or more, if it does it's probably the one you're after, at least with the markup provided in the question

```
function fixLastCell($table){
    var $cells    = $table.find('td,th');
    var $lastCell = $cells.last();
    var $prevCell = $cells.eq( $cells.index( $lastCell ) - 1 );

    $lastCell = $prevCell.attr('rowspan') > 1 ? $prevCell : $lastCell;

    $lastCell.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2bwn1nun/2/)

Comment: Interesting. Even more interesting, the reason I needed the bottom-right cell in the first place is compute the offset of the table (by looking at that cell's contents. For some elements (usually ones that get scrollbars), the `.offset()` returns (0,0), or anyway less than the size of the actual content, and I need to parse the children to get a correct value. I was under the impression that this can also happen with `<table` elements. So, can the `<table>.offset()` be trusted? (I'll do some more experimenting on my own, too)

Comment: If for some reason the table itself has an overflow and a scrollbar, the offset would probably not match, but that can also be fixed by using the scrollheight / width instead of the visible height / width etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have select the tds and ths in the table with rowspan and loop on them with `.each()` and if the current have after it a trs more than rowspan so neglect it else select it.

**EXAMPLE**
if `rowspan=2` then if there are after it 2 tr tags so select the last td else if there are one tr tag so select currant td with rowspan

Here is a way to do so:

```js
function fixLastCell($table){
    
    var $rowspan = $table.find('td[rowspan],th[rowspan]');
    var last=false;
    $rowspan.each(function(){
      crntTR=$(this).parent();
      var spans = $(this).attr('rowspan');
      for(var i =1;i<=spans;i++)
      {
         crntTR= crntTR.next('td,th');
      }
      console.log(crntTR.html());
      if( crntTR.html()== undefined)
        last = $(this);
    })
    var $lastCell = $table.find('td,th').last();
  if(last)
    $lastCell=last;
    
    $lastCell.css('background-color', 'red');
}

fixLastCell($('#t0'));

fixLastCell($('#t1'));

fixLastCell($('#t2'));

fixLastCell($('#t3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="t0" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4 - ok</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t1" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><td>1</td><td rowspan="2">2<br> this one is</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3 <br/>this isn't the cell you're looking for</td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<table id="t2" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th>TH2 - ok</th></tr>
</table>
<p>
    <table id="t3" border="1" width="200">
    <tr><th>TH1</th><th rowspan="2">TH2</th></tr>
    <tr><td>3 <br/>still wrong</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice! Does this also work with colspans? (Intuitively, I think it does. Checking...)

Comment: there are no problem with `colspan` from the beginning so it work fine with my code

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this,

```js
function find($table) {
  var $element, j = -1,
    span;
  $table.find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    if (j < i) {
      span = $(el).children('td,th').last().attr('rowspan');
      j = span ? parseInt(span, 10) + i + j : j;
      $element = $(el).children('td,th').last();
    }
  });
  return $element;
}

function fixLastCell($table) {
  var $lastCell = find($table);
  $lastCell.css('background-color', 'red');
}

fixLastCell($('#t0'));
fixLastCell($('#t1'));
fixLastCell($('#t2'));
fixLastCell($('#t3'));
fixLastCell($('#t4'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="t0" border="1" width="200">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4 - ok</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="t1" border="1" width="200">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">2
      <br>this one is</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3
      <br/>this isn't the cell you're looking for</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="t2" border="1" width="200">
  <tr>
    <th>TH1</th>
    <th>TH2 - ok</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="t3" border="1" width="200">
  <tr>
    <th>TH1</th>
    <th rowspan="2">TH2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3
      <br/>still wrong</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table id="t4" border="1" width="200">
  <tr>
    <th>TH1</th>
    <th rowspan="3">TH2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3
      <br/>still wrong</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3
      <br/>still wrong</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3
      <br/>still wrong</td>
    <td>last</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here getting each row of the table and finding the rowspan value of last td or tr element. After if it is defined then skipping the rows upto rowspan value.

Comment: This seems to work. I had some trouble figuring out what this does: `j = span ? parseInt(span, 10) + i + j : j;` - maybe give more meaningful names, to make it more readable: `j` -> `nextRowToCheck`; `i` -> `currentRow`

Comment: Also, I liked that you split the 'finding' and 'fixing' responsibilities to separate functions. SRP is always a good thing

Comment: if rowpan is not specified then the value of span will be `undefined`, that line is to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I think this selector will work

```
    function fixLastCell($table){   
    var $lastCell = $table.find("tr td[rowspan]:last,tr th[rowspan]:last");

    if($lastCell.length===0){
        $lastCell = $table.find("tr:last td:last,tr:last th:last");
    }

    $lastCell.css('background-color', 'red');

}
```

Comment: why not i table_id it change it to t0 like

Comment: just try the function that i have created in the answer

Comment: please check the function

Comment: That is basically [@OddDev's idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30371947/11545), modified to use the `:last` selector instead of the `.last()` method. It doesn't work, just as OddDev's solution doesn't work. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/5Loye84s/2/ . I appreciate that you don't give up easily, though, so I've removed my negative vote.